# inner join exibir último status

Tags: mysql

preciso obter dados de 3 tabelas através de um filtro em 2 delas usando os critérios Data e Status, sendo que a Data é feita em uma tabela e o Status em outra.

Ocorre que quando a mais de um status com o mesmo nome ele lista todos, gostaria de obter o último status.

query usada:

```
SELECT
numero.id,
numero.numero,
status.status,
status.data
FROM numero
INNER JOIN dados ON numero.id = dados.id_numero
INNER JOIN status ON numero.numero = status.numero AND status.status = 'Confirmado'
WHERE dados.data BETWEEN '2015-04-10' AND '2015-04-10 23:59:59.997' ORDER BY dados.data
```

Demonstrativo Online: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4537f/3/0)

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do output que desejas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendo que, quando dizes, "ultimo status" pretendes devolver apenas aquele que tem a data mais recente. Se assim for podes simplesmente fazer:

```
SELECT   numero.id,
         numero.numero,
         status.status,
         MAX(status.data) DATA
FROM numero
INNER JOIN dados 
   ON numero.id = dados.id_numero
INNER JOIN status 
   ON numero.numero = status.numero 
  AND status.status = 'Confirmado'
WHERE dados.data BETWEEN '2015-04-10' AND '2015-04-10 23:59:59.997' 
GROUP BY numero.id, numero.numero, status.status 
ORDER BY dados.data
```

Comment: muito obrigado @bruno ;)

Comment: Não tem problema. É um prazer poder ajudar! Sempre dá para distrair do trabalho :)

Comment: tem Skype @bruno?

Comment: Aqui não, mas podes falar no chat, acho eu.

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer um `GROUP BY numero.id`

```
SELECT
  numero.id,
  numero.numero,
  status.status,
  status.data
FROM numero
INNER JOIN dados ON numero.id = dados.id_numero
INNER JOIN status ON numero.numero = status.numero AND status.status = 'Confirmado'
WHERE dados.data BETWEEN '2015-04-10' AND '2015-04-10 23:59:59.997'
GROUP BY numero.id
ORDER BY dados.data
```

Comment: grato pela ajuda, então... com o `GROUP BY` ele me trás o primeiro status que no exemplo acima é **2015-04-11** sendo que preciso que seja o último, que no caso é de **2015-04-15**

Comment: Não basta apenas o group by pelo numero.id. Dessa forma perde alguns dos resultados.