# Obter campo relativo a maior data

Tags: mysql

Ontem o pessoal me ajudou a obter o [último status](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60651/inner-join-exibir-%C3%BAltimo-status) referente a maior data, ou seja exibir o status da última modificação.

Agora surgiu-me outra dificuldade relacionada a mesma questão porém com múltiplos status me retornar não só a última data como o status referente a essa última data.

exemplo:

```
// TABELA STATUS
(Numero: 10507, Status: Aguardando, Data: 2015-04-11 09:48:19),
(Numero: 10508, Status: Aguardando, Data: 2015-04-11 11:48:19),
(Numero: 10507, Status: Confirmado, Data: 2015-04-12 10:50:58),
(Numero: 10508, Status: Bloqueado, Data: 2015-04-12 11:50:58),
(Numero: 10507, Status: Despachado, Data: 2015-04-15 15:50:58), // RESULTADO PRETENDIDO
(Numero: 10508, Status: Confirmado, Data: 2015-04-15 16:50:58); // RESULTADO PRETENDIDO

// FILTRO
SELECT
numero.id,
numero.numero,
status.status,
MAX(status.data) AS data
FROM numero
INNER JOIN dados ON numero.id = dados.id_numero
INNER JOIN status ON 
(numero.numero = status.numero AND status.status = 'Confirmado') OR
(numero.numero = status.numero AND status.status = 'Despachado')
WHERE dados.data BETWEEN '2015-04-10' AND '2015-04-10 23:59:59.997'
GROUP BY numero.numero
ORDER BY dados.data

// RESULTADO DO FILTRO
|   id  |   numero  |   status      |   data    |
|   4   |   10507   |   Confirmado  |   April, 15 2015 15:50:58 |
|   5   |   10508   |   Confirmado  |   April, 15 2015 16:50:58 |

// RESULTADO PRETENDIDO
|   id  |   numero  |   status      |   data    |
|   4   |   10507   |   Despachado  |   April, 15 2015 15:50:58 |
|   5   |   10508   |   Confirmado  |   April, 15 2015 16:50:58 |
```

DEMO: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62a0c/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Retorne o MAX(status.status)

```
SELECT
numero.id,
numero.numero,
MAX(status.status),
MAX(status.data) AS data
FROM numero
INNER JOIN dados ON numero.id = dados.id_numero
INNER JOIN status ON 
(numero.numero = status.numero AND status.status = 'Confirmado') OR
(numero.numero = status.numero AND status.status = 'Despachado')
WHERE dados.data BETWEEN '2015-04-10' AND '2015-04-10 23:59:59.997'
GROUP BY numero.numero
ORDER BY dados.data
```

Isto apenas funciona porque, por sorte sua, "Despachado" é maior que "Confirmado" tanto como *string* como na sequência do seu fluxo.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62a0c/6)

Comment: realmente funciona! mas não teria outra forma, sem contar com "minha sorte"?

Comment: Assim de repente não encontro outra.

Comment: Você tem, para o mesmo `numero.numero`, dois registos que obedecem ao critério, um com `status = Confirmado` e outro com `status = Despachado` como você quer trazer apenas o maior não encontro outra forma a não ser `MAX(status.status) `.

Comment: Se você alterar a clausula *GROUP BY* do *SQL* da sua pergunta para `GROUP BY numero.numero, status.status` verá que são trazidos 3 registos com as datas corretamente atribuidas.

Comment: achei outra forma, da uma olhada e diga-nos o que achas :D [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62a0c/12/0)

Comment: É melhor, já que o que você quer é obter o status com maior data. Outra coisa, apesar do MySQL não o obrigar, é boa prática incluir na cláusula *ORDER BY* todas as *(nonaggregated)* colunas que são indicadas no *SELECT*, isto irá evitar situações como aquela em que a sua *query* retornou um `status = Confirmada` com a data do status Despachado.

Comment: Tendi, brigadão @ramaral